# Very slow boot on Ubuntu GNOME 16.10

Tags: boot, partitioning, fstab

I've recently moved to Ubuntu from Windows 10 and noticed a significant drop in booting speed. I've tried to find the solution to my problem on the Internet but failed.

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

gives me following:

```
         22.181s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         14.209s snapd.firstboot.service
         12.125s dev-sdb1.device
         10.708s networking.service
         10.528s apport.service
         10.197s ModemManager.service
          9.015s apparmor.service
          5.811s grub-common.service
          5.544s speech-dispatcher.service
          5.458s irqbalance.service
          5.455s systemd-udevd.service
          5.290s systemd-logind.service
          5.144s gpu-manager.service
          5.143s pppd-dns.service
          4.914s avahi-daemon.service
          4.516s NetworkManager.service
          3.739s accounts-daemon.service
          3.182s polkitd.service
          3.081s thermald.service
          2.711s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          2.175s rsyslog.service
          1.832s plymouth-start.service
          1.670s keyboard-setup.service
```

I am a mere novice in Ubuntu as I've been using Windows for all my life. I am also just an intermediate computer user so these lines don't give me much information

I've also read that my problem could be related to missmatching UUID of swap partition in of fstab file which is not my case.

```
sudo blkid
```

give me

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="7091fe2d-6f35-417e-ac8d-6378ece33b30" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="5812a99e-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="681819bb-3063-4734-9a40-a0ada019cf99" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="5812a99e-02"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="1b698478-f32d-4a9a-963c-8853331c6a74" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ecfba038-01"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="257c98ed-10bd-4f5d-977a-2ae06639155d" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="ecfba038-05"
```

and i have the following in my fstab file

```
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=1b698478-f32d-4a9a-963c-8853331c6a74 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=257c98ed-10bd-4f5d-977a-2ae06639155d none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: first check for your hardware, in this case the harddrive https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-10; it would be also helpful if you could provide us with more info on cpu and ram; the biggest culprit can be eliminated, by removing `splash` from the boot options in `/etc/default/grub` don't forget to run `update-grub` thereafter.